# Page Permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, publishing-page

I have to set permissions on a unique page to a unique user. How can this be done?

Example:

I have a home site collection and a page called "Info". I have to allow all users to see this page but just "TestUser" to edit it.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Go the Page "Info", Click on "Page" tab next to browse, Click on Page Permissions button. 
On Permissions tab click stop permissions. Now Grant Permission to your 'TestUser' to "Edit". Edit the permissions of all the groups and members to "Read".

Comment: dont working. dont show the ribbon to TestUsers. i setup full control for him and READ for everyone